# LEFT JOIN not showing days with zero COUNT

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to retrieve data from the last X days, counting the new rows per day. I need to get also the days that have COUNT = 0.

My query right now is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CAST(TIMESTAMP_T AS DATE) 
FROM TABLE_A a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT CAST(CALENDAR_DATE AS DATE) as DATE0 
      FROM   SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR) b 
ON       CAST(a.TIMESTAMP_T AS DATE)  =  b.DATE0 
WHERE    b.DATE0 BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY AND CURRENT_DATE 
GROUP BY CAST(a.TIMESTAMP_T AS DATE) 
ORDER BY CAST(a.TIMESTAMP_T AS DATE) DESC
```

It is returning the following:

```
255 2019-11-07
922 2019-11-06
342 2019-11-05
176 2019-11-04
18  2019-11-02
224 2019-11-01
```

As you can see, there are days that are not being displayed by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simplify it like so:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(a.TIMESTAMP_T), b.CALENDAR_DATE
FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR b
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A a ON CAST(a.TIMESTAMP_T AS DATE) = b.CALENDAR_DATE
WHERE b.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY AND CURRENT_DATE 
GROUP BY b.CALENDAR_DATE
ORDER BY b.CALENDAR_DATE DESC
```

A couple notes:

- the `calendar_date` field in the `sys_calendar.calendar` view is `DATE`, no need to cast it
- Teradata lets you reference aliased columns without having to do an outer `SELECT`
- replaced `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(a.TIMESTAMP_T)` for a more accurate count (thanks jarlh)

Comment: It's simpler using `b.CALENDAR_DATE` instead of `CAST(TIMESTAMP_T AS DATE)` in the Select list.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead, to include those days:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.TIMESTAMP_T), b.DATE0
FROM TABLE_A a
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN(SELECT CAST(CALENDAR_DATE AS DATE) as DATE0 FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR) b ON CAST(a.TIMESTAMP_T AS DATE)=b.DATE0
WHERE b.DATE0 BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY b.DATE0
ORDER BY b.DATE DESC
```

Since you want all calendar days, even those without any TABLE_A rows.

`COUNT()` a table_a column, to get 0 for non-existing table_a days. (`COUNT(*)` would return 1...)

Answer (score 0):

Interchange the join either right outer join or reverse the tables as the data in the calendar table would be more

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain more on this ? Will Table A have dates only if they have entries. Assuming that , I had similar requirement :

select temp1.qwer ,count(temp1.DATDAY)
from (
select * from 
(SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 AS qwer
FROM dual t
CONNECT BY TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'MM') = TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'))temp
LEFT JOIN 
Temp1_check t1 on temp.qwer=t1.DATDAY )temp1
group by temp1.qwer
order by temp1.qwer;

This query will generate the list of entries in the month and count how many entries were made on Temp1_check.

Temp1_Check with have the list of dates and their respective entries. for eg : If November 9 th have 10 tries then November 9 th will get repeated with the other details of the entries. Hope this helps. If you can elaborate bit more , i can help you achieve your requirement.

Thanks.